# Python - How to convert array elements into strings

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array, myArray, and it has 4 elements.

`myArray = [myFunc(), "Pears", myFunc(), "Pears"]`

My objective is to change the function call of myFunc() to become a string like so "myFunc()"

You can see the problem that there's two function calls inside the array, and they must be converted to string types. The "Pears" string is fine, I don't need to touch that. I also cannot change the myFunc() in any way. I don't have access to it. Otherwise if I did, I could've simply returned a string. In my case I don't have access to it, so I must figure a way out to convert its type from `None` to `String`

Here's what I tried so far

`print( str ( myArray ) )`

this prints
`[None, "Pears", None, "Pears"]`

Something else I tried is this:

`for item in myArray: if not ( isinstance(item, str) ): print( str( item ) )`

this ends up printing this: `None` twice. The idea is to grab every non string from the array and convert it to string. Doesn't work as you can see

I'm out of ideas, I couldn't find anything on Google. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is no way to do it. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want such thing in the first place?

Comment: To which str do you want to convert `None`? `"None"` or `""` or the literal `"myFunc()"`?

Comment: It's not clear why you don't just put quotes around `myFunc()` if that's what you want the array to have.

Comment: I need myFunc() to become "myFunc()" from my understanding, the type of myFunc() is None

Comment: @meniman98 It's not the type of `myFunc()` it is what it returns.

Comment: Good question Mark. The array has already been initialised. It is already populated with loads of elements

Comment: `myArray = ["myFunc()" if x is None else x for x in myArray]`, if it helps.

Comment: @Asocia I need to achieve this because the program I'm working with requires strings from the array, it shows an error because there's a function call inside. The function call must be a string, and it must be read as a string. My objective is to turn myFunc() into "myFunc()"

Comment: @schwobaseggl instead of recommending partial solutions I think it would be better to point the OP in the right direction. What if `myArray` contains `None` as a literal? This will fail. There is no need to complicate things, imo.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I will implement your solution. I'll take a moment

Comment: Could you provide an output how you want it to look? Or briefly explain what myFunc() does?

Comment: I want the output of the iteration to be: ["myFunc()", "Pears", "myFunc()", "Pears"]

Comment: @meniman98: _I also cannot change the myFunc()_ does that mean you cannot change the function or the call in the array ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer This means I can't add or modify code from the myFunc() function. I'm only interested in iterating through the array and converted myfunc() to "myFunc()"

Answer (score 2):

`print(str(myArray))` is printing the correct values, because it is converting the return value of `myFunc()` (which is `None`) into a string. Here is what is happening:

1. You define your array as `myArray = [myFunc(), "Pears", myFunc(), "Pears"]`
2. The above statement causes `myFunc` to be evaluated (called) and the *result* of my `myFunc` is what is places in the array.

Therefore when the array definition statement is executed the array is evaluated to `[None, "Pears", None, "Pears"]` because calling `myFunc()` returns `None`. At this point there is no way to determine where the `None` came from, basically there is no way to tell if the `None` was returned by `myFunc()`, hardcoded in or returned by another method.

3. When you attempt to print the values in the array the values are `[None, "Pears", None, "Pears"]` because that is what the array contains at that point in time.

Another way to think of it is that the `myFunc()` function call got replaced with the result of calling that function because the `()` means call the function and give me it's value.

Comment: I understood your answer, perhaps now that I think about it, I worded the question wrongly. What I want is for the array to read myFunc() like "myFunc()" regardless of what is returns

Comment: @meniman98 You *simply* can't. There is literally no way.

Comment: @meniman98: Asocia is correct, there is no way to do what you want to do. I edited my answer to hopefully make it clearer.